# Bind ComboBox items to property of list of radiobuttons wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I have a `ComboBox` which I wish to bind to an `ObservableCollection<RadioButton>`. However, I wish to list the `ToolTip` property in the `ComboBox` and not actual `RadioButtons`.

**Example:**

If I have 3 `RadioButtons` with `ToolTips` 1, 2, and 3. I wish the `ComboBox` to contain 3 string items, 1, 2 and 3.

**Code:**

*View:*

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LandmarkIdComboBox" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="ToolTip" ItemsSource="{Binding Landmarks, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLandmark, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

*ViewModel:*

```
private ObservableCollection<RadioButton> m_landmarks = new ObservableCollection<RadioButton>();
private RadioButton m_selectedLandmark;

public ObservableCollection<RadioButton> Landmarks
{
    get => m_landmarks;
    set
    {
        m_landmarks = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public RadioButton SelectedLandmark
{
    get => m_selectedLandmark;
    set
    {
        m_selectedLandmark = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Using the above code I can see the mentioned 1,2 and 3 items, but I cannot select them. I guess because they are not regular items but `RadioButtons` so clicking them makes them Checked/UnChecked rather than selected.

I could use an additional `Strruct/Class` to achieve what I need, but of course I prefer not to, if there is another way.

So, is there another way?

Comment: Remove the `MVVM` tag cause ViewModel should NOT be aware of the UI elements. And instead if you want  to see tooltip then create list of strings and populate it from the `RadioButtons`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the selection that is the issue here but rather the fact that `RadioButton` is a `ContentControl`. This means that its `Content` is displayed when selected in a `ComboBox`.

You could fix this by defining a custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LandmarkIdComboBox" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Landmarks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLandmark}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```

Defining an `ObservableCollection<RadioButton>` in a view model breaks the MVVM pattern though but I guess you have your reasons.